# EWS Managed API Issue Accessing Address Fields

Tags: api, dictionary, exchangewebservices

We are using EWS Managed API to access exchange contacts. However for some of the contacts we are not able to access address related fields from exchange contacts. Here is the error message which are getting :-

Error Message
The given key was not present in the dictionary.

Here is the code snippet which we have used to access address related field 
contactItem.PhysicalAddresses[PhysicalAddressKey.Home].Street = “Test Address”

For most of the contacts this code snippet work well, but some of the contacts we got an error. Can anyone please let us know what’s the reason for this error ? Is there issue with these particular exchange contacts that we can’t access address related fields?

Regards
Vipul

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the contact in question doesn't have an existing Home address, and you're trying to just access what is essentially a null entry. Have you tried checking if it is null first, then  creating a new address?

```
if (contactItem.PhysicalAddresses[PhysicalAddressKey.Home] == null)
{
    contactItem.PhysicalAddresses[PhysicalAddressKey.Home] =
        new PhysicalAddressEntry();
}
```